# Illustrator : how do I see the sequence of transformations that are applied to an object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

In Illustrator, I have this object (text in my case) on which some shearing, rotation, probably scaling has been applied. I'd like to look at these transformations and modify or reset one or more of them?
I suppose I would find this in the Appearance window but it's not there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, illustrator has a bit of a peculiar transformation stack. And it does not always yield the result one would expect it to do. In addition it has a tendency to reset transformations from time to time without asking the user. But when it does work then the info is available in the transform palette (found in **Window → Transform**).

[image]

**Image 1**: Transform palette. But even same shape can have different rotation. Depending on how it was made of if illustrator chose to reset your transform at some point.

Also note this does not let you access the underlying transform as it still reports the reference point for x and y from a computed value.

**Note**: For text there is a seond transform. And that is the trasform applied inb for each character. That you can find in the character panel.

Comment: Um ... This might come a little late, but thank you for your answer, that's what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @Herby you should tick the accept checkmark